# Pymongo filter slowing down the query?

Tags: python, pymongo

Do regex pymongo filters slow down queries? I have about 1 million entries I need to sort through with regex filters on one of the fields. I'm returning only some of the fields, so my code is something like:

```
FILTER = {'$and': [
    {'url': {'$not': REGEX}},
    {'url': {'$not': REGEX}},
    {'url': {'$not': REGEX}},
    {'url': {'$not': REGEX}},
    {'url': {'$not': REGEX}},
    {'url': {'$not': REGEX}},
    {'url': {'$not': REGEX}},
    {'url': {'$not': REGEX}},
    {'url': {'$not': REGEX}},
    {'url': {'$not': REGEX}}
]}
cursor = db.info.find(FILTER, FIELDS, batch_size=1000)

random_url_list = []
for i, scrape in enumerate(random_url_cursor):
    if i % 50 == 0:
        print(i, scrape)
    random_url_list.append(scrape)
```

I've been trying to run this for a while but it's just not working. Does filtering with regex like this increase time complexity?

Comment: Yes, for two reasons. First, processing the regex per document is not free and could potentially be expensive. Secondly, you are only going to see rows once you start to find them and that might require searching through thousands to get enough to return the first page.

Comment: I assume you have multiple `REGEX` right, not just the same one a dozen times?

Comment: Yes, it's a dictionary. Would it be faster if I just grab everything and then filter in pandas? @JonSG

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to combine your regex statement into a single one. if not, perhaps you can reorder the tests so that the ones that are most likely to fail are first in the list.

Comment: It's a bunch of and-not-equal-to statements, which sadly can't be done in regex (I think, since there is no and operator). Each regex is about as likely as the last. Think: and not Jane, and not Jack, and not Bill, etc., only with regex.

Comment: Why not `FILTER = {"url": {"$not":{"$regex": "regex1|regex2|regex3|...|regexN"}}}`?  Here's a [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sEybGImHrTn).

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 're.Pattern' and 're.Pattern'`

Comment: What version of the MongoDB server are you using?  You can see that it works on mongoplayground.net.  Perhaps you should show the full code that you tried and the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

well yes, the more proceessing you're doing your likely to face increased processing time but to retrieve from the db itself it shouldn't really be super slow. But it also comes down to what you're running the db off of, if you run it off of your own server (like a VPS or a custom dedicated machine) then it should work fine depending on the specs of the server but if you're using Mongodb atlas that can sometimes be very slow in my experience

If you're not getting anything at all check what is actually being filtered because there's a chance then that you're queries are invalid

Comment: The queries themselves are fine, but it's taking about 30 seconds for each one to return. Edit: actually, I'm trying to run it now, and for about 3 minutes not one entry has returned.

Comment: @F1gN3wt0n in that case it is most likely just the speed of the cluster are you running atlas or something else?